# Subtraction in Power BI Matrix Aggregation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table with the following contents:

```
Header Subheader Subheader2 Amount
   A       B          C       10
   A       B          D       20
```

This is then represented as a power bi matrix:

```
Header     Amount
 A           30
   B         30
     C       10
     D       20
```

I have a situation which requires the aggregation to roll up to a subtraction rather than an addition. So the value of B should be `C - D` (`10 - 20`) instead of (`C + D`) without reversing the sign of `D`. So the matrix should look like:

```
Header     Amount
 A          -10
   B        -10
     C       10
     D       20
```

Any DAX measure I can create to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give some context as to what these values represent? I don't understand why you want to aggregate this way and can't give a general solution without additional context.

Comment: @AlexisOlson The header, subheader and so on are basically stages of a process which we want to calculate an amount of. These come from a dimension table which has been converted into a hierarchy using http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2011/02/15/powerpivot-and-parent-child-hierarchies.aspx. This is then put into powerbi matrix by having a relationship with the leaf nodes(in this case C & D) of a fact table for whom the amounts are present. Let me know in case of any further clarifications.

Comment: So what does `B = -10` mean? Why are you taking the difference of leaf nodes? How do you pick which one is negative and which is positive?

Comment: These are formula's which need to be included in the structure. In this case, to calculate B it is C - D.

Comment: That didn't answer any of the questions I asked. You'll need to clarify if you want people to be able to give a useful answer.

Comment: The report that we are trying to create is a hierarchical structure consisting of various stages (Parent node or A or B) and the processes involved in them (Child node or B, C, D). We need to account for all the amounts across all stages. The amounts are recorded at the leaf node levels (C or D) and then aggregated at higher levels (A or B). B however is not calculated as (C + D) but (C-D). We need a measure which includes such an operation over and above the standard aggregation(addition) without reversing the sign of D. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you give additional (different) examples of a table and desired output?  I think that might readers understand what you are ultimately after.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
Measure =
    IF(HASONEVALUE(Table1[Subheader2]),
        ABS(SUM(Table1[Amount])),
        SUM(Table1[Amount]))
```

Comment: This didn't work. The result I get is:
Row Labels Measure
    A                    -10
    B                    -10
       C            -30
       D            -20

Although the totals I get are correct, the child values(C&D) have been changed and their signs reversed.
I understand that the issue I am facing is not a general issue but could you please specify as to what further reasoning you would require? Which part did not make sense?

Comment: You have not explained the logic behind why you want to combine values in this way. What do these aggregated values represent? What do they mean with regard to that stage or process?

Comment: I am basically trying to recreate an SAP report within powerbi. The SAP report has the same formula within its hierarchy structure. The values are costs associated with each stage for which we want to find an aggregate value. And as explained earlier some of these aggregations are not sums but subtractions.

Comment: So basically, you have some debits and some credits and the aggregates are the sum of these, but at the leaf level you want to show the absolute value instead of the signed value?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much the gist of it.

Comment: Are the amounts signed your source data? If not, how do you know which are debits and which are credits?

Comment: Yes these are coming from relevant source tables. We don't know which are debits or credits, we are just bringing in the numbers as they are and trying to get the aggregated values of the parents node correctly.

Comment: Well, once you've stripped their sign and only have positive numbers to work with without any way to know if it's a debit or credit, then you're out of luck and it's not possible to aggregate them how you want since you don't know which are negative. I'd recommend just summing the signed values (regular `SUM` or `SUMX`) and taking the absolute value at the leaf level. See my edit.